# No error when using AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am using Crypto++ to Encrypt and Decrypt a File with the following code:

```
try {

    EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived.data(), 32, ivb, ivb.size());
    FileSource f(fileUrl.c_str(), false,
                 new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor, new FileSink(
                         std::string(fileUrl).c_str()),  CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |  CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END ));
    std::fstream file(fileUrl, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    size_t remaining = file.tellg();
    file.close();
    size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 16384;
    while (remaining && !f.SourceExhausted()) {
        const unsigned int req = STDMIN(remaining, BLOCK_SIZE);
        f.Pump(req);
        f.Flush(false);
        remaining -= req;
    }

} catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
    cout << e.GetWhat();
    return 5;
}
```

Decryption:

```
try {

    EAX<AES>::Decryption decryptor;
    decryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived2.data(), 32, ivb2, ivb2.size());

    FileSource fe(fileUrl.c_str(), false,
                  new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(decryptor, new FileSink(
                          std::string(fileUrl).c_str()), CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |  CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END ));

    file.open(fileUrl, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    size_t remaining = file.tellg();
    remaining -= 3;
    file.close();

    size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 16384;
    while (remaining && !fe.SourceExhausted()) {
        const unsigned int req = STDMIN(remaining, BLOCK_SIZE);
        fe.Pump(req);
        fe.Flush(false);

        remaining -= req;
    }
} catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
    cout << e.GetWhat();
    return 5;
}
```

My Problem is, that this Method is not throwing an Error when decrypting no matter what inputs are used. I can modify the encrypted file or use another password or whatever, I only get an incorrectly decrypted file, but no exception.

As far as I have read, the `AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter` should check for this stuff automatically and throw an exception.

Why is not throwing any exception?

Comment: I reached out to the author of the Crypto++ library about this use case. He's very busy with other things nowadays, so he does not have the spare cycles to work on these issues. But he remains available to answer questions for us. Once we get pointed in the general direction, I hope we can check-in a fix for your issue. I hope its as simple as a new flag  and maybe ***`VERIFY_MAC`***, which performs the mac verification without the decryption. And maybe ***`IGNORE_MAC`***, which allows you to decrypt-only once you verify the mac.

Answer (score 2):

> My Problem is, that this Method is not throwing an Error when decrypting no matter what inputs are used. I can modify the encrypted file or use another password or whatever, I only get an incorrectly decrypted file, but no exception...
>   
>   Why is not throwing any exception?

The short of it is, ***`FileSource file(url.c_str(), false, new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter...)`*** means the message is ***not*** `Put` because ***`pumpAll=false`***. Because the message is not `Put`, ***`LastPut`***, which triggers the MAC verification, is not called. You can trigger it with ***`MessageEnd`***, but you are not at the end of the message, so that's always going to fail.

I understand what you are trying to do, and the fix is trickier.

---

In the big picture, nearly everything is OK. You are using authenticated encryption and MAC'ing before you consume the data. But I'm wondering if the single or "one shot" MAC is the way to approach the problem.

To use the single MAC in this case, you probably want to disgorge decryption from verification. You still want to do them, but you want to do them as separate steps. Before decryption, you will verify the MAC over the entire message (read-only operation, fast). Once the MAC verifies, you then perform decryption (read-write operation, slow). Unfortunately, the library does not offer a separate ***`EAX_Mac`*** class that you can key, consume the message and then determine if the MAC is good.

Maybe the way to go is to apply a MAC at each block sized data unit, like 4096 or 16384. This is the use case or handling envisioned by folks like Bernstein in the [CAESAR Competition](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html). The competition is for the next generation of authenticated encryption schemes. Unfortunately, the library does not have a filter set to do it.

---

Applying the MAC on block sized data units through a custom filter is possible, and its an interesting problem in security engineering because each security context must be unique. I think the way to approach it is...

Create a `BlockedAuthenticatedEncryptionFilter`. Instead of keying the encryptor object:

```
EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived.data(), derived.size(), iv, iv.size());
```

key the `BlockedAuthenticatedEncryptionFilter` instead:

```
FileSource f(... new BlockedAuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(
    encryptor,
    key.data(), key.size(),
    iv, iv.size(),
    new FileSink(...));
```

Now, `BlockedAuthenticatedEncryptionFilter` will accumulate source data. Whenever a full block is available, it performs the authenticated encryption on the block under the key and iv. That's an encryption under a security context (***`{message,key,iv}`***), so the security context must be changed for the next block or message. That's why the filter is keyed rather than the mode.

To change the security context ***`{message,key,iv}`*** for the next message, you might be able to do a simple `Increment` on both the key and iv. That will ensure the security context is unique for each message.

One thing you ***can't*** do is call `encryptor.GetNextIV()` to get the next *deterministic* iv derived from the cipher's state. That's because, by design, the library does not offer it. This comes up on occasion on the mailing list, but I can't find a sample message at the moment.

However, I'm not sure what troubles `next_key = Increment(key)` and `next_iv = Increment(iv)` could cause, so I would need to think about it and research it a bit. I would probably ask about it on the [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or the [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), too.